# Why isn't Visual Studio showing a unsigned value as int?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, int, unsigned

I'm using VS 2012 and I'm reading this book that teaches the bases of C\C++. The book is quite old and it teaches not in VS, but in Borland C++. There is this lesson that teaches how to convert a unsigned value to `int`. In the book it says that `int` numbers have values from -32768 and 32767, and unsigned have from 0 to 65535. In the book it is given the number 42000 and shows that as `unsigned` is 42000 and as `int` is -23536. In VS it shows that both as `unsigned`, and as `int` is 42000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    unsigned int value = 42000;

    printf("Show 42000 as unsigned %u\n", value);
    printf("Show 42000 as int %d\n", value);

}
```

Output:

```
Show 42000 as unsigned 42000
Show 42000 as int 42000
```

Side note: tried both `%d` and `%i`; didn't worked.

Comment: Because size of `int` is architecture specific. The new architectures might have different size. You can check it using the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: that book refers to 16-bit ints, newer architectures support higher numbers of bits

Comment: And the standard remark: There is no such a language "C/C++"

Comment: The size of the integer data-types depend on the compiler and the platform. Generally speaking you could say that `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) && sideof(short) <= sizeof(int) && sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) && sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`. `int` was supposed to be the "native word" on the platform, but isn't anymore since it's seldom 64 bits on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Why do people insist on learning archaic versions of C from ridiculously old books? This book likely predates C99, possibly even C89/C90; it's basically the best way to end up getting stymied by small problems like this over and over. Next up will be the question on using x86 segment selectors and near pointers vs. far pointers.

Comment: "Why do people insist on learning archaic versions of C from ridiculously old books?" --> likely cost.  Some folks access and ability to use low-cost up-to-date material is severely limited.

Answer (score 9):

Your old book gives ranges for 16-bit `int` and `unsigned`. The newer compiler uses ether 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 7):

## Burn that book. It was never correct.

The minimum range for an `int` is -32767 to +32767 since it *could* be a 1's complement 16 bit number.

The maximum range is not specified.

VS typically uses a 32 bit 2's complement value for an `int`.

By the way, the behaviour of using `%d` for an `unsigned` is **undefined**. If you write that and compile the code, then the compiler reserves the right to eat your cat. If the book used that construct and claimed it was portable, then **burn it again**.

Comment: The result of casting is implementation defined, and the book is compiler specific, so I guess if we take it as one, it can stay... in a museum.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: but asserting that range for `int` was just plain naughty.

Comment: The Borland compiler he's using targets a PC, which is two's complement. Using %d for unsigned may be implementation specific, but it will work for Borland with 16 bit integers and with Visual Studio with 32 bit integers.

Comment: That may well be the case but the OP is clearly not aware that the Borland book is written for a language called "Borland C++"; whatever that is. I find the volume of rubbish out there simply distressing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Casting rules don't apply here. Undefined behaviour is a result for using incorrect with type with incorrect conversion specifier.

Answer (score 4):

More than likely you have a 32 bit wide int which can hold [–2147483648, 2147483647] so you are not overflowing it like the book is trying to example.  Try it with a value greater than 2147483647 but smaller than 4294967295 which is the max value a 32 but unsigned integer can hold.

Answer (score 4):

What the book says is true, assuming `int` is 16 bit.  On most modern compilers, it is 32 or 64 bit.

If you want to illustrate this point with the given values, VS supplies `__int16` and `unsigned __int16` which are integer types guananteed to be 16 bits.

EDIT:

You can also use the standard types `int16_t` and `uint16_t` starting with VS 2010 and later.  Be sure to `#include <stdint.h>` to get access to them.

Comment: or for VS, you can also use short for a 16 bit signed integer, unsigned short for a 16 unsigned integer. You could also write your own typedefs similar to stdint.h, which unfortunately some versions of VS do not have (stdint.h). These would be int16_t for signed 16 bit, or uint16_t for unsigned 16 bit.

Comment: BTW, one could use `uint16_t` for unsigned and `int16_t` for signed from `<stdint.h` or `<cstdint>` depending on the language.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the acceptable ranges of signed and unsigned integers.

To do this in C you have to include header

```
#include <limits.h>
```

and use constants

```
INT_MAX
INT_MIN
UINT_MAX
UINT_MIN
```

For example

```
printf( "INT_MAX = %d\n", INT_MAX );
```

In C++ you can do the same using header

```
#include <limits>
```

For example

```
std::cout << "The maximnun value of type int is " 
          << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
          << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Borland C++ is very old and has gone through many transitions - now known as Embarcadero's XE Suite. Like it's been said, that book is making assumptions that you're using a 16 bit compiler, so maybe it's worth finding something a bit more up to date :)